# Streaming an RTMP live stream from NGINX to Icecast2 on CentOS

Tags: centos, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

I have had success with using `exec_push` in `NGINX`'s RTMP module to have `FFMPEG` convert live streams to `HLS`.

The next thing that I would like to do is publish an audio stream from the same source to `Icecast`, located on the same server.  From my research, it seems that `ffmpeg` cannot broadcast to `Icecast`, so I have turned to `VLC`.  I have tried many combinations of commands over SSH to try and achieve this.  Here is what I have managed to construct out of them combinations, which gives me the least amount of warnings:

```
vlc -vvv 'rtmp://localhost/stream/here'  --no-sout-video --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=aac,ab=128,channels=2, channel_layout=stereo,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout{mp3, bitrate=128, samplerate=44100, channels=2},mux=ogg, channel_layout=stereo,dst=source:pass@domain:8000/mount, select=novideo}" --sout-keep
```

I will add the output of this command to the end of this question as it is quite long.

This will establish a connection to `Icecast` which I can see on `Icecast`'s admin page.  You can also connect to it with a player like `VLC` or `WMP` and get the correct title, but it is not playing any audio.  If I `ffprobe` the `Icecast` stream, it hangs until the the stream has been quit.

I do not know if the `vlc` command is producing bad audio, or it if is because I am missing something to do with it being a live stream.  If I swap out the input for a standard file, it will behave the same and quit after a short period of time, as if it has processed the file from start to finish as an encoding.

Knowing that I am able to make good use of `ffmpeg`, I thought I would try the initial conversion to audio with that, then pipe the output to `vlc` for streaming to `Icecast`.  To be honest, I have probably just made a complete mess of that as I can see the output flowing on my SSH terminal rather than getting any kind of stream from the attempt.

I couldn't say exactly what that attempt was, but from the look of my pastings, it would have been along the lines of (with and without the `#transcode`):

```
ffmpeg -i *input* -acodec libfaac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -f adts - | vlc - --no-sout-video :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=shout,mp3,dst=*serverinfo*} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

The current setup has people streaming to `NGINX` using Flash media Live Encoder 3.2, AAC Audio @ 128k, 44100, Stereo.  H.264 ~200k.  The reason for these attempts is to enable multiple streams with only 1 encoder.

**My questions are:**

1. Have I missed anything in my original `VLC` command which would mess up the stream, or
2. Will any of my remaining warnings prevent what I am trying to do.
3. Have I missed a much easier way to achieve what I am trying to do?

**The first part of `VLC`'s output:**
Configure info removed for post size.  http://pastebin.com/qJedPYvY

```
[~]# vlc -vvv 'rtmp://localhost/stream/here'  --no-sout-video --sout "#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=aac,ab=128,channels=2, channel_layout=stereo,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout{mp3, bitrate=128, samplerate=44100, channels=2},mux=ogg, channel_layout=stereo,dst=source:pass@domain.com:8000/mount, select=novideo}" --sout-keep
VLC media player 2.0.7 Twoflower (revision 2.0.6-54-g7dd7e4d)
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.0.7 Twoflower
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2013 VLC authors and VideoLAN
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: revision 2.0.6-54-g7dd7e4d
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 413 modules
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/chrisday/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: looking for memcpy module: 4 candidates
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc debug: using memcpy module "memcpymmxext"
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1d9a8d8] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 3 candidates
[0x1d9a8d8] main demux debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
[0x1d9a8d8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 82.713 ms - Total 82.713 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 82.713 ms)
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1d9b758] main access debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
[0x1d9b758] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1d9b758] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0x1d9b758] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 18.675 ms - Total 18.675 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 18.675 ms)
[0x1da2b68] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x1da2b68] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x1da2b68] main stream debug: received first data after 5 ms
[0x1da2b68] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 57 KiB/s
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 64.976 ms - Total 64.976 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 64.976 ms)
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.246 ms - Total 0.246 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.246 ms)
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x1d9d028] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 1 candidate
[0x1d9d028] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0x1d9d028] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0x1d9d028] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 10.341 ms - Total 10.341 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 10.341 ms)
[0x1da0fb8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x1da0fb8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1da0fb8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1da0fb8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x1da0fb8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x1da0fb8] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x1da0fb8] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 60.204 ms - Total 60.204 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 60.204 ms)
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0x1dbb1e8] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module: 1 candidate
[0x1dbb1e8] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0x1dbb1e8] main xml reader debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.974 ms - Total 2.974 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.974 ms)
[0x1d9d028] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: EOF reached
[0x1d9d028] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0x1da2dc8] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
[0x1d9b758] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0x1d95f78] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'Media Library' : 242.644 ms - Total 242.644 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 242.644 ms)
[0x1d9a798] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x1d9a798] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0x1d9a798] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 10.167 ms - Total 10.167 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 10.167 ms)
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x1d96c88] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: no interface module matching "inhibit,none" could be loaded
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 9.367 ms - Total 9.367 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 9.367 ms)
[0x1d96c88] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: playlist threads correctly activated
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: adding item `rtmp://localhost/stream/here' ( rtmp://localhost/stream/here )
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 0 items, index -1
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: no interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none" could be loaded
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 19.787 ms - Total 19.787 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 19.787 ms)
[0x1d96c88] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x1ccb108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x1d96c88] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 5 candidates
[0x1d96c88] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
[0x1d96c88] skins2 interface debug: Cannot open X display
[0x1d96c88] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x1d96c88] [cli] lua interface debug: Found lua interface script: /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac
[0x1d96c88] [cli] main interface debug: using interface module "lua"
[0x1d96c88] [cli] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 324.791 ms - Total 324.791 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 324.791 ms)
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: resyncing on rtmp://localhost/stream/here
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: rtmp://localhost/stream/here is at 0
[0x1dac818] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Creating an input for 'rtmp://localhost/stream/here'
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=aac,ab=128,channels=2, channel_layout=stereo,samplerate=44100}:gather:std{access=shout{mp3, bitrate=128, samplerate=44100, channels=2,},mux=ogg, channel_layout=stereo,dst=source:pass@domain:8000/mount, select=novideo}'
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: stream=`std'
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-standard-access to shout{mp3, bitrate=128, samplerate=44100, channels=2}
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-standard-mux to ogg
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out warning: option channel_layout is unknown
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-standard-dst to source:pass@domain:8000/mount
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out warning: option select is unknown
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: looking for sout access module: 1 candidate
[0x1d96c88] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.0.7 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: set config option: sout-shout-mp3 to (null)
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: set config option: sout-shout-bitrate to 128
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: set config option: sout-shout-samplerate to 44100
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: set config option: sout-shout-channels to 2
[0x7f10540047f8] access_output_shout access out warning: failed to connect using 'icy' (shoutcast) protocol
[0x7f10540047f8] access_output_shout access out debug: connected using 'http' (icecast 2.x) protocol
[0x7f10540047f8] access_output_shout access out debug: shout access output opened (source@domain:8000//mpont)
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: using sout access module "access_output_shout"
[0x7f10540047f8] main access out debug: TIMER module_need() : 165.432 ms - Total 165.432 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 165.432 ms)
[0x7f1054005f08] main mux debug: looking for sout mux module: 1 candidate
[0x7f1054005f08] mux_ogg mux: Open
[0x7f1054005f08] main mux debug: using sout mux module "mux_ogg"
[0x7f1054005f08] main mux debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.991 ms - Total 2.991 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.991 ms)
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: muxer support adding stream at any time
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: muxer prefers to wait for all ES before starting to mux
[0x7f1054001a38] stream_out_standard stream out debug: using `shout{mp3, bitrate=128, samplerate=44100, channels=2}/ogg://source:pass@domain:8000/mount'
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_standard"
[0x7f1054001a38] main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 171.004 ms - Total 171.004 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 171.004 ms)
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: stream=`gather'
[0x7f1054006508] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
[0x7f1054006508] main stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_gather"
[0x7f1054006508] main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.182 ms - Total 0.182 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.182 ms)
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: stream=`transcode'
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-vcodec to none
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-acodec to aac
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-ab to 128
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-channels to 2
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out warning: option channel_layout is unknown
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-transcode-samplerate to 44100
[0x7f1054006c48] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: codec audio=aac  44100Hz 2 channels 128Kb/s
[0x7f1054006c48] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: codec video=none 0x0 scaling: 0.000000 0kb/s
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_transcode"
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.498 ms - Total 0.498 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.498 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: `rtmp://localhost/stream/here' gives access `rtmp' demux `' path `localhost/stream/here'
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: creating demux: access='rtmp' demux='' location='localhost/stream/here file='/stream/here'
[0x7f10540033a8] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 0 candidates
[0x7f10540033a8] main demux debug: no access_demux module matched "rtmp"
[0x7f10540033a8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.025 ms - Total 0.025 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.025 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: creating access 'rtmp' location='localhost/stream/here', path='/stream/here'
[0x7f10540033a8] main access debug: looking for access module: 1 candidate
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
[0x7f10540033a8] access_avio access debug: not seekable, size=-38
[0x7f10540033a8] main access debug: using access module "access_avio"
[0x7f10540033a8] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 425.679 ms - Total 425.679 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 425.679 ms)
[0x7f10541738f8] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x7f10541738f8] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
Metadata:
  Server                NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
  width                 320.00
  height                180.00
  displayWidth          320.00
  displayHeight         180.00
  duration              0.00
  framerate             15.00
  fps                   15.00
  videodatarate         200.00
  videocodecid          0.00
  audiodatarate         128.00
  audiocodecid          0.00
  profile
  level
[0x7f10541738f8] main stream debug: received first data after 2228 ms
[0x7f10541738f8] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 2s - 0 KiB/s
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.116 ms - Total 0.116 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.116 ms)
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0x7f1054173c28] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.045 ms - Total 0.045 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.045 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: creating demux: access='rtmp' demux='' location='localhost/stream/here' file='/stream/here'
[0x7f1054173d58] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 53 candidates
[0x7f1054173d58] ts demux debug: TS module discarded (lost sync)
[0x7f1054173d58] mod demux debug: MOD validation failed (ext=)
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug: trying url: /stream/here
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug: detected format: flv
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug: adding es: video codec = h264
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug: adding es: audio codec = mp4a
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug: AVFormat supported stream
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug:     - format = flv (FLV (Flash Video))
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug:     - start time = 11122000
[0x7f1054173d58] avformat demux debug:     - duration = 0
[0x7f1054173d58] main demux debug: using demux module "avformat"
[0x7f1054173d58] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 3349.695 ms - Total 3349.695 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3349.695 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: video is disabled, not selecting ES 0x0
[0x7f1054d7c378] main decoder debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
[0x7f1054d7c378] packetizer_mpeg4audio decoder debug: running MPEG4 audio packetizer
[0x7f1054d7c378] packetizer_mpeg4audio decoder debug: AAC 44100Hz 1024 samples/frame
[0x7f1054d7c378] main decoder debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_mpeg4audio"
[0x7f1054d7c378] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 122.949 ms - Total 122.949 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 122.949 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: starting in sync mode
[0x7f1054db9e28] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x7f1054db9e28] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1054db9e28] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1054db9e28] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib64/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x7f1054db9e28] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f1054db9e28] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7f1054db9e28] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.459 ms - Total 0.459 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.459 ms)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: `rtmp://localhost/stream/here' successfully opened
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: switching to async mode
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 7%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7f1054001078] main stream output debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:0x7f103c0008e0)
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7f1054006c48] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: creating audio transcoding from fcc=`mp4a' to fcc=`aac '
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 13%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 31%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 35%
[0x7f103c0009e8] main generic debug: looking for decoder module: 31 candidates
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 35%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 35%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 54%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 56%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 56%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 56%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 77%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 77%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 77%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 92%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 93%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Buffering 93%
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Stream buffering done (325 ms in 0 ms)
[0x7f103c0009e8] main generic debug: using decoder module "faad"
[0x7f103c0009e8] main generic debug: TIMER module_need() : 69.890 ms - Total 69.890 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 69.890 ms)
[0x7f103c000e28] main encoder debug: looking for encoder module: 13 candidates
[0x7f103c000e28] avcodec encoder debug: libavcodec initialized (interface 0x365664)
[libfaac @ 0x7f103c012c20] Channel layout not specified
[0x7f103c000e28] avcodec encoder debug: found encoder MPEG AAC Audio
[0x7f103c000e28] main encoder debug: using encoder module "avcodec"
[0x7f103c000e28] main encoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 105.148 ms - Total 105.148 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 105.148 ms)
[0x7f1054006c48] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: Looking for filter (f32l->s16l, channels 2->2, rate 44100->44100)
[0x7f103c00d008] main filter debug: looking for audio filter module: 13 candidates
[0x7f103c00d008] audio_format filter debug: f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 32->16
[0x7f103c00d008] main filter debug: using audio filter module "audio_format"
[0x7f103c00d008] main filter debug: TIMER module_need() : 59.176 ms - Total 59.176 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 59.176 ms)
[0x7f1054006c48] main stream out debug: Filter 'audio_format' (0x7f103c00d008) appended to chain
[0x7f1054006c48] stream_out_transcode stream out debug: Got complete audio filter chain
[0x7f1054006508] stream_out_gather stream out debug: creating new output
[0x7f1054005f08] main mux debug: adding a new input
[0x7f1054005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: adding input
[0x7f1054005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: mp4a stream
[0x7f1058000b28] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 234 ms
[0x7f103c0009e8] faad generic warning: decoded zero sample
[0x7f1054005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: writing header
[0x7f1054005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: creating header for mp4a
```

**Output pauses here.  If quit, the following output is received:**

```
q
Shutting down.
[0x800c88] [cli] lua interface: Requested shutdown.
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: exiting
Error in `q' libvlc's "q" is not a command
Bye-bye!
> [0x735108] main libvlc debug: deactivating the playlist
[0x816818] main playlist debug: deactivating the playlist
[0x816818] main playlist debug: incoming request - stopping current input
[0x816818] main playlist debug: dying input
[0x7fdc3c000b28] main input debug: control: stopping input
[0x816818] main playlist debug: dying input
[0x7fdc38d7c378] main decoder debug: removing module "packetizer_mpeg4audio"
[0x7fdc38d7c378] main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `mp4a', 0 PES in FIFO
[0x7fdc38001078] main stream output debug: removing a sout input (sout_input:0x7fdc240008e0)
[0x7fdc24000e28] main encoder debug: TIMER encoding audio frame : 0.417 ms - Total 463.316 ms / 1043 intvls (Avg 0.444 ms)
[0x7fdc240009e8] main generic debug: removing module "faad"
[0x7fdc24000e28] main encoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
[libfaac @ 0x7fdc24012c20] 4 frames left in the queue on closing
[0x7fdc38006c48] main stream out debug: Filter 0x7fdc2400d008 removed from chain
[0x7fdc2400d008] main filter debug: removing module "audio_format"
[0x7fdc38173d58] main demux debug: removing module "avformat"
[0x7fdc38173c28] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
[0x7fdc380033a8] main access debug: removing module "access_avio"
[0x7fdc3c000b28] main input debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
[0x816818] main playlist debug: dead input
[0x7fdc3c000b28] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'rtmp://localhost/stream/here' : 6014.355 ms - Total 6014.355 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 6014.355 ms)
[0x7fdc38001078] main stream output debug: destroying useless sout
[0x7fdc38006c48] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=transcode)
[0x7fdc38006c48] main stream out debug: removing module "stream_out_transcode"
[0x7fdc38006c48] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[0x7fdc38006508] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=gather)
[0x7fdc38006508] main stream out debug: removing module "stream_out_gather"
[0x7fdc38005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: removing input
[0x7fdc38005f08] main mux warning: no more input streams for this mux
[0x7fdc38006508] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[0x7fdc38001a38] main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=std)
[0x7fdc38001a38] main stream out debug: removing module "stream_out_standard"
[0x7fdc38005f08] main mux debug: removing module "mux_ogg"
[0x7fdc38005f08] mux_ogg mux: Close
[0x7fdc38005f08] mux_ogg mux debug: writing footer
[0x7fdc380047f8] main access out debug: removing module "access_output_shout"
[0x7fdc380047f8] access_output_shout access out debug: shout access output closed
[0x7fdc38001a38] main stream out debug: destroying chain done
[0x8380b8] main playlist export debug: saving Media Library to file /home/chrisday/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[0x8380b8] main playlist export debug: looking for playlist export module: 1 candidate
[0x8380b8] main playlist export debug: using playlist export module "export"
[0x8380b8] main playlist export debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.213 ms - Total 0.213 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.213 ms)
[0x8380b8] main playlist export debug: removing module "export"
[0x816818] main playlist debug: playlist correctly deactivated
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: removing all services discovery tasks
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: removing all interfaces
[0x800c88] [cli] main interface debug: removing module "lua"
[0x804798] main interface debug: removing module "hotkeys"
[0x816818] main playlist debug: destroying
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: TIMER ML Load : Total 4.090 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.090 ms)
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: TIMER Items array build : Total 0.037 ms / 2 intvls (Avg 0.019 ms)
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: TIMER ML Dump : Total 13.059 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 13.059 ms)
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: removing stats
[0x735108] main libvlc debug: removing module "memcpymmxext"
```

Many Thanks!
Chris

Comment: In answer to #3, and if you have a Linux box to host the software, have you looked at Savonet/Liquidsoap?

Comment: wow, thank's joat.  I'm going to have a good play with this.  It looks like it will do exactly what I need.  If nothing goes up for question one, i'll ask you to add this as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Not a problem.  I'm a fan of Liquidsoap.  It's one shortcoming is that it requires a moderate amount of horsepower to do the transcoding.